# Avoid counting note pages in beamer

Tags: beamer

I am generating quite a few version of slides for a lecture and I generally want that slide number stay consistent throughout, regardless what version i am using. For example, I have a presentation mode where I use black frames to create breaks where I can interact with students -- and I do not want them to get a slide count because they are not part of the handout version.

I now noticed that note slides (\note{}) seem to also get a page number when they are generated into a pdf. So, in the example below, i get page number 3 for slide "TWO" when I genearte in just-for-me mode and page number 2 in presentation mode. I do not want that. I want that note slides do not increase the count. How do I do that?

I have the following mini example that highlights my point. Please play with the two modes to see the difference in numbering:

```
% presentation mode
%\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

% just-for-me mode
\documentclass[notes, hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

% some adaptations
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.99\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=1ex,right]{xxx}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertpagenumber{} \hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stuff}
    \framesubtitle{Sub-Stuff}
    \centering \LARGE ONE
\end{frame}
\note{
Some notes to explain what stuff really is...
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stuff}
    \framesubtitle{Sub-Stuff}
    \centering \LARGE TWO
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `\insertframenumber` instead of `\insertpagenumber`:

```
% presentation mode
%\documentclass[hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

% just-for-me mode
\documentclass[notes, hyperref={pdfpagemode=FullScreen},xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\begin{document}

% some adaptations
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.99\paperwidth,ht=0ex,dp=1ex,right]{xxx}%
    \hspace*{6em}
    \insertframenumber{} \hspace*{1ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stuff}
    \framesubtitle{Sub-Stuff}
    \centering \LARGE ONE
\end{frame}
\note{
Some notes to explain what stuff really is...
}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Stuff}
    \framesubtitle{Sub-Stuff}
    \centering \LARGE TWO
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @RalfB I second the usage of `\insertframenumber` because like this you can very easily create pause frames which are empty and unnumbered with `\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain]`